# What variable types can I add to an s3 objects' metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-metadata

Which of the common types can I add to an S3 objects' metadata? Int, float, str, bool, ect ...?

Comment: They are US-ASCII strings afaik.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. Do you happen to have a source for it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume, according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-object-metadata.html#add-object-metadata-user-defined) that they must be string types

> You can assign user-defined metadata to an object. User-defined
>   metadata must begin with the prefix "x-amz-meta-", otherwise Amazon S3
>   will not set the key value pair as you define it. You define custom
>   metadata by adding a name that you choose to the x-amz-meta- key. This
>   creates a custom key. For example, if you add the custom name
>   alt-name, the metadata key would be x-amz-meta-alt-name.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [User-Defined Object Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata):

> Each key-value pair must conform to US-ASCII when you are using REST and to UTF-8 when you are using SOAP or browser-based uploads via POST.

I'm assuming you're using REST.